# How to configure error page location for NonexistentConversationException?

Tags: jsf, cdi, custom-error-pages, weld, conversation-scope

I need help handling the expired/non-existent conversation when `?cid=XX` is in the URL. I have tried to put

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException</exception-type>
    <location>/faces/index.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.jboss.weld.context.NonexistentConversationException</exception-type>
    <location>/faces/index.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

However these didn't work. I still get the error and couldn't forward to `index.xhtml`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to to explicitly specify that a conversation shouldn't be propagated for a particular request. Add `nocid=true` as a parameter at the end of your index.xhtml.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.jboss.weld.context.NonexistentConversationException</exception-type>
    <location>/faces/index.xhtml?nocid=true</location>
</error-page>
```

Refer to the following link
[expired conversations involving CDI and JSF](http://planet.jboss.org/post/custom_error_pages_for_expired_conversations_involving_cdi_and_jsf)

Answer (score 2):

The ancester to the weld exception works in web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.enterprise.context.NonexistentConversationException</exception-type>
    <location>/index.xhtml?nocid=true</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: This is true for Wildfly 12 and 13. If you are using Wildfly 10 or 11 the exception type "org.jboss.weld.context.NonexistentConversationException" should be chosen.